# Edit Leaderboards and Achievements while waiting for upload in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, publish

I have one iOS application already on the store which is V1.0. I have added a new version 1.1 to the store and made it "Waiting for upload". By Mistake, I forgot to add Leaderboards and Achievements in Game Center to my new version 1.1. But the same is present in my older version V1.0.

Can somebody tell me if they will allow me to update Leaderboards and Achievements to my new version after uploading binary? Or there are other alternates available for this kind of issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If GameCenter code is already added in version 1.0 and selected in iTunesConenct for 1.0 then no need to select same for version 1.1. It works.

You need to select only if added in 1.1 version.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dear, actually they showed me the leaderboards and achievements table blank for version 1.1, that is why I was afraid they will not let me add later on.

Comment: Just for curiosity, if I reject the uploaded binary of new version, will it allow me to edit the leaderboards for new version?

Comment: I tried rejecting uploaded binary of new version 1.1. Still it did not allow me to edit leaderboards. Anyways I have uploaded again. Let's  hope that my new version automatically gets the leaderboards of V1.0.

Comment: ok, don't worry leaderboard from 1.0 you get. After deletion what was app status? during prepare for upload only not able to edit leader board?